# Rmarkdown knitting error: Error in dirname(name) : path too long

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, string-length

When I run my Rmarkdown program interactively chunk-by-chunk, the program runs successfully without errors, however, when I try to knit it, I get this error message:

```
Error in dirname(name) : path too long
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: if working under Windows, you'll perhaps need to enable [long path](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error message, check the length of your code chunks in your Rmarkdown code. I was getting the above error because one of my chunks were named as follows:

````
```{r additional descriptives and other statistical tests tests,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
````

Through trial and error, I found out the **maximum length for the code chunk description is 48 characters**. As long as the description has 48 or fewer characters, this error will not get triggered.